# error: 'Qt::ConnectionType' is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, compiler-errors, connection

I compiled a code in win7 and worked fine and now when I compile it in ubuntu this error is appeared :

```
error: 'Qt::ConnectionType' is not a class or namespace
```

it happens in this line :

```
connect(serial , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(readData()) , Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);
```

I can't find the solution.
What should I do?
and sorry for my english language.

Comment: Try to simply use `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Qt::ConectionType` is an `enum` and `enum`s dump their symbols into the containing namespace in C++. (While `class enum` don't do this and form their own namespace). Thus

```
connect(serial , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(readData()) , Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);
```

is not correct, but

```
connect(serial , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(readData()) , Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

is. By the way, there is a new `connect`-Syntax available with Qt 5 giving you compile-time type safety. It looks like this:

```
connect(serial, &QIODevice::readyRead,this , &ClassOfThis::readData, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason it works on Windows 7 is that you are using a different compiler, namely Microsoft's Visual C++ which supports the non-standard extension that allows you to qualify the name of your enum, GCC does not support this extension. As ever you should be [checking your warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173704.aspx) as so often the answer lies there.